# How to fix issues with custom slick slider inside Elementor?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, slick.js, elementor

I need to add a custom looking slider to website made on Elementor.
[The website itself](https://radhanim.co.il/)

I didn't make it from the start, I just have to fix slider.  Not that one from premium features - it has to look different.
I added the custom post type called 'slider', and use it for a loop, like I always do without elementor.

```
// Shortcode to output custom PHP in Elementor
function wpc_elementor_shortcode( $atts ) {?>
    <section class="slider-section">
        <div class="slider-section-inner">
            
        
        <div class="slider-item-wrapper">
      <?php
      global $post;
      $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type' => 'slider');
      $myposts = get_posts( $args );
      foreach($myposts as $post){ setup_postdata($post); ?>
            
        
                <div class="slider-item">   
                       <div class="slider-item-inner d-flex">
                    <div class="slider-item-img">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail()?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slider-item-text">
                        <h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
                            <?php the_title()?>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <span class="jet-headline__label">
                            <?php the_excerpt()?>
                            </span>
                            <div class="content-button">
                                <?php the_content()?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
   
    
        <?php 
      }
      wp_reset_postdata();
      ?>
        </div>
    </div>     
    </section>
<?php }
add_shortcode( 'my_elementor_php_output', 'wpc_elementor_shortcode');
```

Added its loop to the shortcode, pasted the shortcode to the text block, and one item appears correctly, but something wrong with the slick.
Then added the script to functions.php

```
add_action('wp_footer','slider_main');
function slider_main(){?>
    <script>
                        jQuery(document).ready(function(){                              
                        
                        jQuery('section.slider-section .content-button a').addClass('raven-button raven-button-link elementor-animation-grow'); 
                    
                        jQuery('.slider-item-wrapper').each(function() {
                          var slider = jQuery(this);
                          slider.slick({                                                  
                          slidesToShow: 1,
                          slidesToScroll: 1,
                          dots:false,
                          arrows: true,
                        });
                        });                                                     
                            
                        });
                        </script>   
    
    
<?php }
```

It's fully white, I don't see it.
I experemented to change containers and wrappers, but it's still something wrong. Please help - maybe I miss something.
Is it a script or maybe a style?

```
section.slider-section {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 90px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    overflow-x:hidden
}

.slider-item-inner.d-flex {
    display: flex;
        align-items: center;
   
}
.slider-item-img {
    width: 50%;
}

.slider-item-img img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.slider-item-text {
    width: 50%;
}

section.slider-section h2.elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-default {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Alef", Sans-serif;
    font-size: 120px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 83px;
      margin-right:50px
}

.slider-section-inner{
    max-width:1140px;
} 


section.slider-section .slick-track{
    display:flex!important;
    justify-content:center;
}

section.slider-section span.jet-headline__label {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Alef", Sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

span.jet-headline__label p {
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-color: #E1FF25;
}

.slider-item-text p {
    display: flex;
    width: fit-content;
}

.slider-item-text .d-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-width: 24vw;    
     margin-right:50px
}

.content-button a {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    background-color: #E1FF25;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-family: "Alef", Sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #000000;
}
.raven-button:focus, .raven-button:hover, .raven-button:visited, a.raven-button:focus, a.raven-button:hover, a.raven-button:visited{
    color:unset!important;
    text-decoration:none!important
}
```

Comment: avoid flexbox for the `slider-section`. the slider is actually there and rendered but is offset & invisible due to `overflow:hidden`. so either u miss some styles or ruin it with your styles.

Comment: I disabled infinite, it helped to see the first item, but the second is still invisible